# HDMI Receiver Sense Logic and TMDS Capacitor Coupling

Tags: hdmi

Does anybody know how is the "receiver sense" logic done?

As the [datasheet for Sil9612 4K video processor puts it in section 2.13.8 "receiver sense and hot plug detection"](http://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/DataSheets/ASSP/SiI-DS-1120_Public.ashx): it is "by sensing the termination in the attached device". How exactly the termination is sensed?

The [HDCP specification](https://www.digital-cp.com/sites/default/files/HDCP_Specification%20Rev1_3.pdf) explained the use of HPD (hot-plug detection) and RSEN (receiver sense): When HPD is high, the source reads EDID through I2C from the sink. Then when the RSEN goes high, the source turns on the TMDS signal in an appropriate format.

Now we have a board that uses 100n capacitors on each of the TMDS lines to make an AC coupling of the signal. Would that be a problem to this receiver sensing?

Comment: TMDS is specified to have DC coupling.

Comment: Yes, after removing the coupling capacitors, it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about HDMI hot plug detection, but I guess all recent high-speed serial busses (DC de-coupled) use the the same technique as in USB 3.x standard. They use the idea that unterminated differential line has shorter RC time when charged by a pulse up (only parasitic line capacitance is present), while terminated line will have the RC close to AC decoupling capacitor. There is a picture from most recent USB 3.2 specifications, section 6.11.1:

[image]

See Section 6.11.2 for more details of the Rx detect sequence.

Comment: A [USB3.0 spec pdf is available online](https://www.usb3.com/whitepapers/USB%203%200%20(11132008)-final.pdf).

Comment: @minghua, thanks. For USB 3.0, the Rx Detect is shown on Figure 6.23, same thing. Just in case, all USB specs are available at USB.ORG, only they come all packaged into one big zip file, http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_32_030818.zip

Comment: I thought USB specs were members only. Great to know it has changed.

Comment: @minghua, No, I was dealing with USB for at least 18 years, and the specs were always in open access.

Comment: Great to know it's always been free! I'll know where to look next time. Thanks!